# Fastest method to find map keys in a vector

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, stdvector, unordered-map

I'm looking for the faster method to extract the map values filtered by vector keys.

Below the standard code:

```
    std::unordered_map<uint32, user> map;
    std::vector<uint32> to_find; 
    std::vector<user> results;

    auto it = map.begin();

    while (it != map.end())
    {
        if (std::find(to_find.begin(), to_find.end(), it->first) == to_find.end())
            results.push_back(it->second);
        it++;
    }
```

Comment: "find map keys by vector" may be too vague a phrase for readers to know _exactly_ what you are asking.

Comment: your code doesnt make much sense. You iterate the map and for each entry you try to find that exact entry, if you cannot find it you push it into the vector, but the condition in your if will never be true because each entry in the map is in the map.... What do you acutally want to do`?

Comment: oh, wronged code. I'm editing it

Comment: You have `O(N + M)` (with code a la `merge`) or `O(N * log(M))` (with iterative `map.count`) with N size of `to_find`, and M size of `map`.

Comment: Do you mean `!= to_find_end()` ? is the vector sorted?

Comment: btw why do you use a while loop instead of a for? I mean it does the same but it looks a tiny bit odd

Comment: the problem is not in the xD cycle, but thx for your interest

Comment: to_find is the list of keys to find in map keys

Comment: your code adds elements whose key is not in the vector, dont you want the opposite?

Comment: it's correct, i need the missing keys of vector

Comment: from 0 to 100k (map and vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [std::binary_search()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), which has a time complexity of *O(log n)* where `n` is the size of the vector `to_find`. This could be much better than using `std::find()` which has a linear time complexity.

[DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/jMN7Kh)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using user = int;
using uint32 = unsigned long int;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<uint32, user> myMap = {{1,2},{3,5},{2,9},{4,7}};
    std::vector<uint32> to_find = {1,3};
    std::vector<user> results;

    if(to_find.size() == 0)  // if you have to_find vec size = 0
        std::for_each(myMap.cbegin(), myMap.cend(), [&results](const auto& ele)->void
                                                    {
                                                        results.emplace_back(ele.second);
                                                    });
    else
    {
        for(const auto& it: myMap)// binary_search; if not found add the value
            if(!std::binary_search(to_find.begin(), to_find.end(), it.first))
                results.emplace_back(it.second);
    }

    for(const auto& it: results) std::cout << it << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I need to get the missing data from the Map, so if find_vec is 0 I will add all entries map. It's reverse

Comment: for(const auto& find_this: find_vec) cannot start if find_vec have 0 size

Comment: @FabioZanini: If you do not find a KEY in your to_find vector you wanna save the  VALUE of that KEYs to a new vector, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, but not necessarily in another vector

Answer (score 0):

If both your containers are sorted, a linear way is to use algorithm similar to `std::merge`:

```
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
std::vector<VALUE>
collect_absents(const std::map<KEY, VALUE>& map, const std::vector<KEY>& present)
{
    std::vector<VALUE> res;

    auto mit = map.begin();
    auto vit = present.begin();

    while (mit != map.end() && vit != present.end())
    {
        if (*vit < mit->first) {
            ++vit;   
        } else if (mit->first < *vit) {
            res.push_back(mit->second);
            ++mit;   
        } else { // equal
            ++vit;
            ++mit;
        }
    }
    for (; mit != map.end(); ++mit) {
        res.push_back(mit->second);
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/M1p40t)